# when i run program, get error on (cmd.executenonquery)

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click

    cn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into CandTable(Passport_No,Name,Father 
    Name,Mother Name,Date_of_Birth) values('" & Candi.TxtPass.Text & "','" & 
    Candi.TxtName.Text & "', '" & Candi.TxtFather.Text & "', '" & 
    Candi.TxtMother.Text & "','" & Candi.TxtDob.Text & "')", cn)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()
    MsgBox("Data Saved Successfully")

End Sub
```

Comment: I also recommend you look into parameterizing your SQL query. [Here is an example of doing it in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/542542/19818). Parameterization protects you against quotation marks in strings and other dangerous input, which could give an attacker access to your database.

Comment: I can imagine that this will work: take a quotation mark for the field names containing a whitespace: ChrW(96). Try this: \`Father Name\`,\`Mother Name\`

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```
Using sqlcon As New SqlConnection(strCaseConnString)    
                sbSql.Append("insert into CandTable(Passport_No,Name,[Father Name],[Mother Name],Date_of_Birth) values(@Passport_No,@Name,@FatherName,@MotherName,@Date_of_Birth")    
                Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sbSql.ToString(), sqlcon)
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Passport_No", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Candi.TxtPass.Text
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Candi.TxtName.Text
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FatherName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  Candi.TxtFather.Text
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@MotherName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Candi.TxtMother.Text
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Date_of_Birth", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Candi.TxtDob.Text
                    sqlcon.Open()
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    sqlcon.Close()
                End Using    
            End Using
```

Comment: I think, this will produce an error, too. See my comment above.